# Problema ao implementar Converter JSF com p:selectOneMenu

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou tendo problemas ao implementar um converter para um simples selectOneMenu do Primefaces. Quando passa pelo método getAsObject do Converter o parâmetro value vem com a descrição do que foi selecionado pelo usuário e não com o Id que está no itemValue do `f:selectItems`.

O problema só acontece com o componente do Primefaces, mas com o nativo do JSF não ocorre.

Este é o SelectOneMenu:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="tipoEvolucao" value="#{atendimentoBean.atendimento.tipoEvolucao}" effect="fold">
<f:selectItems value="#{atendimentoBean.tipoEvolucaoList}" itemValue="#{tipoEvolucao.id}"
 var="tipoEvolucao" itemLabel="#{tipoEvolucao.descricao}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Converter

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = TipoEvolucao.class)
public class TipoEvolucaoConverter implements Converter {

    @Inject
    TipoEvolucaoRepository repository;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        TipoEvolucao retorno = null;

        if (value != null && !"".equals(value)){
            try {
                Long id = new Long(value);
                retorno = repository.getById(id);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return retorno;
            }
        }
        return retorno;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value != null && value.getClass().getGenericSuperclass() == GenericEntity.class){
            TipoEvolucao entity = ((TipoEvolucao) value);
            return entity.getId() == null ? null : entity.getId().toString();
        } 
        return null;
    }
}
```

Com isso sempre que eu escolho um valor na na página e o converter vai buscar a informação no banco pelo Id como é padrão ele não retorna nada por nem conseguir converter o valor para Long.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém já teve esse problema com o Primefaces? Mesmo definindo o `itemValue="#{tipoEvolucao.id}"` ele sempre leva a descrição.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No itemValue deixar apenas

```
itemValue="#{tipoEvolucao}"
```

Não precisa mandar o ID, ele já é referenciado no converter.